# How to position content in the bottom center of a layout

Tags: html, css, vaadin

Can you please help me to place the buttons in the bottom center of the horizontal Layout see picture below.
Ps: the top vertical layout has a dynamic height.

Here's my HTML code:

```
<html>

<body>
<div class="container" style="height: 100%">

<div class="v-panel-content v-panel-content-task-search-list-view v-scrollable" tabindex="-1"
     style="position: relative; height: 100%; width: 275px; border-radius: 10px; border-style: none;">
    //-----------------------Vertical Layout
    <div location="loc1"></div>
    <div location="loc2" style="margin-left: 8px;"></div>
    <div location="loc3"></div>
    <div location="loc4"></div>
    //-----------------------HorizontalLayout
    <div location="buttonLayout"></div>
</div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

[image]

Comment: Did you try the [component alignment](https://vaadin.com/docs/-/part/framework/layout/layout-settings.html#layout.settings.alignment) within `HorizontalLayout`?

Answer (score 0):

The dynamicity of the above `<div>` won't make a difference if it's positioned to flow with the document (not absolute, or fixed).

Your bottom `<div>` should have the CSS properties `text-align: center;` applied to it. As you're probably aware, this centralises inline elements within the `<div>`

As your buttons may not be inline elements, we need to set them to `display: inline-block;`. This will position them as text would be positioned within their parent element.

Make sure that they don't have a `float` property applied to them, or else they will align according to this declaration.

See the below fiddle

```css
.lower {
  text-align: center;
  }

.button-lower {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 5px;
  background: green;
  }
```

```html
<div class="lower">
  <a class="button-lower" href="#">Vider</a>  
  <a class="button-lower" href="#">Chercher</a>
  </div>
```